# Application to force a window clickthrough until a hotkey is pressed

Tags: desktop

Is there a way, or application, to allow a window (Such as CMD) to become transparent and click-through until a certain configurable hot-key is pressed?

**Details**

- Open CMD
- Enable click-through and transparency on that CMD window
- Work on other applications etc while the transparent window is behind them all
- On pressing '[Shift] + [Alt]', the CMD window will bring to front, have focus, and now fully visible and clickable

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Added a process tree, hope that's what you needed

Comment: when you say 'click-through and transparency' do you just mean that the command prompt window disappears i.e. is minimized or sent to back (does it matter which?) or that you want some fancy 'transparent' gui effect?

Comment: The thought here is that on a multi-monitor system, with the console over icons, you can click-through to the icons / apps behind it until you use a hotkey to focus